# continuity from below/above in signed measures

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

I think proving continuity from above and below in signed measures is the same as when you prove it for (positive) measures. I just feel silly basically copying down the same proof for an assignment I have to hand in, so I was just wondering if there were any small, yet important observations I should be making. Any small differences?

Answer (score 2):

None I can think of. But if you have the [Hahn decomposition theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn_decomposition_theorem), you can avoid repeating the proof by applying the known continuity result to the positive and negative parts of the measure.